# relativeLayout.rightOf not working properly

Tags: android, runtime, view

I have this code in which i am adding certain views dynamically into a relativeLayout. Problem is despite using the above mentioned feature in the code, all the views are overlapping each other.

```
date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Date);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Save);
    save.setText("Confirm Purchase");
    container=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    items[no]=new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
    items[no].setId(id++);
    container.addView(items[no],p1);
    items[no].setHint("Enter Item");

    quants[no]=new EditText(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p2=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, items[no].getId());
    quants[no].setId(id++);
    container.addView(quants[no],p2);
    quants[no].setHint("Quantity");

    rates[no]=new EditText(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p3=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, quants[no].getId());
    rates[no].setId(id++);
    container.addView(rates[no], p3);
    rates[no].setHint("Rates");

    totals[no]=new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p4=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p4.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, rates[no].getId());
    container.addView(totals[no], p4);
    totals[no].setText("Amount");
```

PlZ dont ask me to do it in XML. Its a piece of a long code.
[image: screenshot]

XML:

```
   <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                 android:id="@+id/container">



  </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: why not do it in XML?

Comment: Why not do it in xml and using `LayoutInflater` to add it dynamically?

Comment: I think you made an error with id numbers, because I see that **Amount** is in the right position

Comment: Try this one `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    container.setLayoutParams(lParams);` - this way you can set the dimensions of the container.

Comment: @g00dy I have set the dimensions of the container in xml. No need to do that.

Comment: @Macialv initailly i also thought but just go through the code everything looks fine to me but still not working

Comment: @kayveesin - ok then ,please paste the XML, I think that the answer can be found there. Thanks

Comment: @g00dy I pasted the XML. Have a look

Comment: found the solution, figured out that the id I was assigning to every view was starting from 0. instead I changed the starting from a different number. The solution worked possibly because initially the ids being assigned may have been used somewhere in the XML

Comment: @kayveesin - i've a suggestion for those ids. In order to keep them "unique", pre-assign them in `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="nameId" type="id"/>
</resources>` then in the code do: `items[no].setId(nameId);`. Do this for the rest of the ids, in order for them not to conflict with the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `RelativeLayout`, you can try using `LinearLayout` instead with which you would relax and not think about relative positions of newly added items. with `LinearLayout` you have to just assign `orientation` property in order for your elements to be displayed in the orientation suitable for your project

Comment: yeah i could, but i have to add views both horizontally and vertically. Whereas linearLayout only allows me to do it in a particular way

Comment: @kayveesin make two layouts

Comment: see, i have to add 4 views every time the user gets focus on the last view of the last row. So accordingly i cannot inflate a layout every time. It will make the app too slow.

Comment: this is the reason i am trying to do in a single layout

Comment: @MocialovBoris - and what if he has several (like 10). That's why the `RelativeLayout` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

1.Your need xml to define all "id" for your controllers. I've not try to use id in codes directly without ids.xml.
2.You might use LinearLayout instead of RelativLayout.

Comment: sorry but i couldn't get u